# SQL Select XML Node based on sibling node attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
<Findings>
   <Finding EcinRecordID="1042893">
      <Name>Goal Length of Stay for the ORG</Name>
      <Selected Value="0" DisplayValue="No"/>
   </Finding>
   <Finding EcinRecordID="1042894">
      <Name>Goal Length of Stay for the GRG</Name>
      <Selected Value="1" DisplayValue="Yes"/>
      <NoteText>3 days</NoteText>
   </Finding>
</Findings>
```

2 challenges:

1. Select node value of Findings/Finding/Name where Findings/Finding/Selected Value = "1"
2. Select node value of Findings/Finding/NoteText where Findings/Finding/Selected Value = "1"

Putting this into a stored procedure.  I've tried at least 3 dozen versions using query, exists and value.  I can get the whether the Selected Value = '1', but can't seem to assign the corresponding Name value in the Select statement.

```
SELECT
   p.value('(Payments[1]/Payment[1]/PreAuthCertNumber)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS PriorAuthNumber
   ,qa.value('(Name[1])','varchar(255)') AS Question
   ,qa.value('(Findings/Finding/Name)[1]','varchar(255)') AS Answer
    FROM #ValueExample
    CROSS APPLY XMLDocument.nodes('/OutboundDataFeed/Patient/PatientAdmission') as t(p)
    CROSS APPLY XMLDocument.nodes('/OutboundDataFeed/Patient/PatientAdmission/CMAssessments/CMAssessment/Sections/Section/Questions/Question') as u(qa)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
declare @XML xml

set @XML = '
<Findings>
   <Finding EcinRecordID="1042893">
      <Name>Goal Length of Stay for the ORG</Name>
      <Selected Value="0" DisplayValue="No"/>
   </Finding>
   <Finding EcinRecordID="1042894">
      <Name>Goal Length of Stay for the GRG</Name>
      <Selected Value="1" DisplayValue="Yes"/>
      <NoteText>3 days</NoteText>
   </Finding>
</Findings>'

select @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding[Selected/@Value = "1"]/Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Name,
       @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding[Selected/@Value = "1"]/NoteText/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as NoteText
```

Result:

```
Name                                     NoteText
---------------------------------------- -------------------------
Goal Length of Stay for the GRG          3 days
```

Comment: Terrific!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, when I went to try to implement this solution in a query of an XML field with which I was working, I found that the syntax provided in Mikael Eriksson's answer above didn't work for me. The structure was correct and I double-checked that it was well-formed, but I'd just get nulls for my results.

The syntax as provided (snipped from Mikael Eriksson's answer) was:

```
select @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding[Selected/@Value = "1"]/Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Name,
       @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding[Selected/@Value = "1"]/NoteText/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as NoteText
```

What I found actually did work for me was to slightly modify it as follows (obviously, this wasn't my own code snippet, but for the purposes of consistency):

```
select @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding/Selected[@Value = "1"]/Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Name,
       @XML.value('(/Findings/Finding/Selected[@Value = "1"]/NoteText/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as NoteText
```

Just thought I'd post as an alternate for anyone else who might run into the same experience I did.

Comment: Thanks @wildwend, I did run into the same issue as you did.